# Can decentralized blockchain technology like bitcoin be used to store medical information?

Tags: blockchain

For example patients get private key, providers get public key?

Comment: I dont get your example, if you mean to encrypt the documents then use gpg, if you mean decentralized storage check out ethereum

Comment: Please give us more details about what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The blockchain is used for more than just storage of data. To store data, all you need is a harddrive of some sort. What kind of things would you like to be able to do with this 'medical blockchain'?

I think that in general, everything medical would be considered confidential, so even if it could be stored in a blockchain, no one would want to.

Answer (score 1):

No. The cost of storing information in decentralized technologies is larger than in centralized.

Comment: That's not really true. It might cost more, and provide no benefit, but you definitely could store medical info like this. A better answer would explain the problems with the approach and how existing alternatives better suit the problem.